# Creating a file using Apple IOS

Tags: iphone, file-io, createfile

Am new to i phone development area.i invoked a sap webservice from i phone.I got the result in the xml format.That in the sense the data with the xml tags is displayed in the console.But from then onwards i want to create a xml file using file I/O concepts in Apple IOS.So that the data in the console which is in the xml format will be moved to the xml file.From there i want to parse the data.Since few days tried using JSON for parsing but By Using JSON can we give our own web service URl or  extension with .json url only works.Can you give brief explanation???

Comment: You are trying to parse an XML data with JSON. That's your first error. Do you really want to save your XML file before processing it? There's no need to - you can do it all in memory. Check the Apple developer documentation for NSXMLParser.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Can you explain me briefly

Comment: Brief explanation - go to developer.apple.com and search for nsxmlparse. Or use google

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vast and simple tutorial that helps to read as well as create xml documents using GDataXMLParser http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml